# matlab traduction to python for simple calculation

Tags: python, matlab

one more time i need your help,
To introduce the problem, i got this :

```matlab
x=[0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8]
y=[9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
x=x(:)
y=y(:)
X=[x.^2, x.*y,y.^2,x,y]

a=sum(X)/(X'*X)
```

```matlab
X=
0   0   81  0   9
1   10  100 1   10
9   33  121 3   11
16  48  144 4   12
25  65  169 5   13
36  84  196 6   14
49  105 225 7   15
64  128 256 8   16

a =
 -0.0139 0.0278 -0.0139 -0.2361 0.2361
```

Considere that the matlab code is absolutely true

and i translate this to :

```py
x=[0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y=[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
X=np.array([x*x,x*y,y*y,x,y]).T
a=np.sum(X)/np.dot(X.T,X)#line with the probleme
```

`X` is the same

But i get (5,5) matrix on `a`

Probleme come from the mult beetwen X.T and X i think, i'll try np.matmul, np.dot, transpose and T and i don't know why i can't get `a` (1,5) or (5,1) vector... what is wrong is the translation beetwen those 2 langage on the a calculation

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Problem is that in matlab version you are using smal x `x` for dot product but in python version you are using captial X `X` for dot product.

Comment: my bad i edit the post

Comment: Lets however, change your assertion: that matlab code is not true. In fact, it errors. Your MATLAB code does not return what you claim, it returns "
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree."

Comment: Is your output of `a` correct in the matlab version?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh we suppose it is ok

Comment: @Cocapy Problem is here is that in matlab `sum` gives a vector containing sum of each column while `np.sum(X)` gives the sum of all the elements. You need to mention axis = 0 in np.sum as `np.sum(X, axis = 0)`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri matlab code is giving to me i can't change it ...

Comment: Your MATLAB code is incorrect because it errors. You are missing transposing `x` and `y`. Otherwise it does not do what you say it does. Just try it, copy paste it in your MATLAB.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh i also try but it doesn't change the  (5,5) but thanks for the try

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks one more time for your anwser i forget to tell that x and y are transpose in columns

Comment: @Cocapy np.dot(X.T, X) is a matrix of size (5, 5). Then how `np.sum(X)/np.dot(X.T, X)` could be a vector?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh i don't know why the matlab code gives me (1,5) i absolutely agree with you ...

Comment: @Cocapy The output of `a` which you are getting from matlab is as you expect it to be?

Comment: absolutely sure

Comment: i suspect that i matlab sum gives me (1,5) and it is considère as mult by X'*X who gives me a correct (1,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division of such two matrices in [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html):

```matlab
s = sum(X)
XX = (X'*X)
a = s / XX
```

is solving for `t` the linear system: `XX * t = s`.

To achieve the same in Python/NumPy, just use [`np.linalg.solve()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) (making sure to use `np.sum()` with the correct `axis` parameter to mimic the same behavior as MATLAB's `sum()`, as indicated in the comments and @AnderBiguri's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66966092/5218354)):

```py
x=np.array([0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y=np.array([9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
X=np.array([x*x,x*y,y*y,x,y]).T
s = np.sum(X, 0)
XX = np.dot(X.T, X)
a = np.linalg.solve(XX, s)
print(a)
# [-0.01388889  0.02777778 -0.01388889 -0.23611111  0.23611111]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `sum`.

In MATLAB, default `sum` sums over the first axis. In `numpy` `sum` sums all the values.

```
a=np.sum(X, axis=0)/np.dot(X.T,X)
```

Comment: i also try but it doesn't change the (5,5) but thanks for the try